# Failed to parse GPIB address

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program to communicate with my Yokogawa digital multimeter. I have NI Visa (version 2022 Q3) and Ni488.2 (version 21.5.0) installed.

My Visa resource name for this device is: GPIB0::20::INSTR

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using NationalInstruments.Visa;

namespace GPIB_DMM_voltage
{
    class program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var session = (Ivi.Visa.IMessageBasedSession)Ivi.Visa.GlobalResourceManager.Open("GPIB0::20::INSTR");
                session.FormattedIO.WriteLine("*IDN?");
                string idName = session.FormattedIO.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine($"*IDN?) = {idName}");
                session.Dispose();
                session = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("press entrer key to end");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I ran it, it is giving me this error.

[image: error message]

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please don't post error messages as images; use text instead